# Chrome-- Background script vs. Content script (page locks up a little and gifs stutter on page load)

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension, background-process, content-script

I have a lot of operations being performed in the content script to determine average colors for a picture, and was wondering if anyone knows whether the background handling this analysis would be less intrusive to the user's browser experience?

Simple question but I would like to know the answer before i rewrite a lot of my code!

Thanks

Comment: Best approach: Don't do the processing in JS.  Offload it to a server running a faster language, and/or a program running in C, Python, etc.  ... ... It's not clear if a content script shares the page thread or the extension (background) thread.  If they are different threads, there *might* be an advantage to doing the processing in the BG.  The BG might also be able to spawn a new thread, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with Brock Adams here, although I do get his point obviously using a faster language is ultimately better, however there are still good/convenient options in js; especially taking in to account peoples cpu core count these days. If you are doing image processing you could do it much quicker by combining the use of a canvas element and the parallel.js lib. This could crunch the numbers much faster and keep it out of your ui threads.

You can use this https://github.com/adambom/parallel.js

This library can spawn as many threads as you like so use canvas to split the image in to blocks then do the processing of each block asynchronously in its own thread. Once complete stitch the image back together in canvas and extract the newly processed image.

There are of course many variations of this theme such as processing multiple images in different threads. The type of image processing you are doing will ultimately determine the best way to utilize the threads. You can pass the images to the background process base64 encoded or use a get request, although you do not need to move to background process if using the above library.